# Migrating library to Webpack from Requirejs with multiple defined modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, requirejs, amd

Currently, we are bundling our JavaScript for the library with requirejs. I have been tasked with migrating to Webpack.

Every module within the built file is accessible using the bundles config.

```
define('internal', function () { // <-- some utility method, class...
     return function () {};
}

...

define('library', ['internal'], function (internal) { // <-- the main module

});
```

Within a consuming app it could look like:

```
define(['internal'], function (internal) {

});
```

As long as the require config has internal within the bundles property like so:

```
bundles: {
    'library': ['internal']
}
```

then the internal module will be used from the library.

I have the file building as a library target in webpack but it is currently not building with multiple named defines.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        library: ['main', 'internal']
    },
    output: {
        library: 'libraryname',
        libraryTarget: 'amd',
        filename: '[name].build.js'
    },
    /**
     Resolve, loaders...
    **/
    plugins: [
         // https://github.com/Waidd/multidefine-library-webpack-plugin
         new MultidefineLibraryWebpackPlugin([/* config */])
    ]
}
```

With that configuration it gets close with the defines built into the library as expected but requirejs will timeout due to it not frequently intaking the global define queue. If I have

```
require(['library'], function () {
    require(['internal'], function () {
        //it will be loaded now
    }
})
```

then it will load as expected but not if they are within the same dependency array.

Is there anyway to get Webpack to define several modules to be consumed externally that is not the 'main' module? How would I be able to externally define modules as they exist in the current requirejs build system?